# Use count() function in ColdFusion query of query

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

I wanted to use `count()` function in ColdFusion Query object.

Here is my code and test:

```
<cfset x = querynew("id,name")>

<cfquery name="y" dbtype="query">
    select count(*) as total from x
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>Test1: #y.total#</cfoutput>

<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(x)>
<cfset Temp = QuerySetCell(x, "id", 1)>
<cfset Temp = QuerySetCell(x, "Name", "Vikas")>

<cfquery name="y" dbtype="query">
    select count(*) as total from x
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>Test2: #y.total#</cfoutput>
```

Should I use convert function? Like if total is [enpty string] then result should be 0.
Or is there any other best/proper way to do that?

Comment: Basically not MATH function `count` but count number of row like `count(*)` in SQL server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does seem like this is a bug, however there is an easy way around it. Simply wrap the y.total in val(), so it would read:

```
<cfoutput>Test1: #val(y.total)#</cfoutput> 
<cfoutput>Test2: #val(y.total)#</cfoutput>
```

val() will return 0 if an empty string is passed to it.

Comment: I ended up with using `recordCount`. But this looks better.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've found a bug in CF here (perhaps log it @ http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html).

The first query should return 0, not [nothing]!

In your simple example, I think just dispense with the QoQ entirely, and just use x.recordCount.

But obviously this is not much chop if you have a WHERE filter in your QoQ, in which case You're gonna need to do something like you suggest.  I can't see a better approach here.

If you raise that bug with Adobe, let us know the bug ref so we can vote for it ;-)

-- 
Adam

Comment: Heh.  I had a search around in the bugbase, and noticed actually *I* raised a bug for this back in 2008: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=73559.  It's not exactly the same, but it's demonstrating the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. I now worked with a workaround, like all the others, who have had this problem. btw: is this link only working, if i am logged in?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the number of rows in de query-object use: #x.recordcount#